# Snapkit and multiple custom cells in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, snapkit

I am using `UItableView` as a base for a user profile page. I have several custom cells. The first custom cell is images wrapped in `scrollview`. I have this error when I open this view:

```
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1c42a2940@CardFullscreenViewController.swift#143 UIScrollView:SCROLL_VIEW.top == Lez.ProfileImagesCell:0x12a02e800.top>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1c02a9180@CardFullscreenViewController.swift#144 UIScrollView:SCROLL_VIEW.height == 512.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1c02a91e0@CardFullscreenViewController.swift#145 UIScrollView:SCROLL_VIEW.bottom == Lez.ProfileImagesCell:0x12a02e800.bottom - 16.0>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0094690 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' Lez.ProfileImagesCell:0x12a02e800'ProfileImagesCell'.height == 44   (active)>"
```

And here is a custom code for this cell:

```
class ProfileImagesCell: UITableViewCell {
    var scrollView = UIScrollView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupScrollView()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    private func setupScrollView() {
        addSubview(scrollView)
        let x = frame.width * 1.6
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(x)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        }
        scrollView.snp.setLabel("SCROLL_VIEW")
        scrollView.auk.settings.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I assume there is something wrong with height, but I can't solve this. Any input is appretiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason behind this conflict `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` is initial height of the cell , you can try to set the priority of the bottom constraint of the scrollView to 999 , I mean this one

```
make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks